# How do I customize wheelnav.js's spreader (with a svg)

Tags: customization, wheelnav.js

I'm using Raphael's [wheelnav.js](http://wheelnavjs.softwaretailoring.net/index.html) and would like to use a SVG I already have, containing two seperate paths, as a spreader. I have found [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43340589/add-circles-at-the-edges-of-wheelnav-items-that-rotates-along-with-it) on customizing the slices, using functions already existing in wheelnav to draw with, but not on how to customize the spreader, using a custom/existing SVG.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry for late response, summertime. :) I hope this helps.

Comment: It helps, and works, thanks :) I'm unfortunately not able to upvote your answer - I'm too new here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an imgsrc feature, where you can use your existing SVG.

```
var wheel = new wheelnav("divWheel");
wheel.spreaderEnable = true;
wheel.spreaderInTitle = "imgsrc:intitle.svg";
wheel.spreaderOutTitle = "imgsrc:outtitle.svg";
wheel.spreaderOutTitleHeight = 50;
wheel.spreaderInTitleHeight = 35;
wheel.spreaderRadius = 0;
wheel.createWheel(["This", "is", "a", "sample"]);
```